ESP32 as Wifi repeater/extender
In trying to make a wifi repeater/extender using the esp32 board
I tried the same with esp8266 and it worked quite well
but I'm having problems to understand the same with esp32
I found the esp8266 code in official arduino examples
ie:
// NAPT example released to public domain
#define STASSID "mynetwork"
#define STAPSK "mynetworkpassword"
#include \<ESP8266WiFi.h\>
#include \<lwip/napt.h\>
#include \<lwip/dns.h\>
#define NAPT 1000
#define NAPT_PORT 10


void setup() {
    Serial.begin(115200);
    Serial.printf("\\n\\nNAPT Range extender\\n");

    WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
    WiFi.begin(STASSID, STAPSK);
    while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
        Serial.print('.');
        delay(500);
    }

    Serial.printf("\\nSTA: %s (dns: %s / %s)\\n", WiFi.localIP().toString().c_str(), WiFi.dnsIP(0).toString().c_str(), WiFi.dnsIP(1).toString().c_str());


    auto& server = WiFi.softAPDhcpServer();
    server.setDns(WiFi.dnsIP(0));
    WiFi.softAPConfig(IPAddress(172, 217, 28, 254), IPAddress(172, 217, 28, 254), IPAddress(255, 255, 255, 0));
    WiFi.softAP(STASSID "extender", STAPSK);
    Serial.printf("AP: %s\\n", WiFi.softAPIP().toString().c_str());

    err_t ret = ip_napt_init(NAPT, NAPT_PORT);
    Serial.printf("ip_napt_init(%d,%d): ret=%d (OK=%d)\\n", NAPT, NAPT_PORT, (int)ret, (int)ERR_OK);
    if (ret == ERR_OK) {
        ret = ip_napt_enable_no(SOFTAP_IF, 1);
        Serial.printf("ip_napt_enable_no(SOFTAP_IF): ret=%d (OK=%d)\\n", (int)ret, (int)ERR_OK);

        if (ret == ERR_OK) {
            Serial.printf("WiFi Network '%s' with same password is now NATed behind '%s'\\n", STASSID "extender", STASSID);
        }
    }

    if (ret != ERR_OK) {
        Serial.printf("NAPT initialization failed\\n");
    }
}

void loop() {}

but I am unable to get the same for esp32
the main thing that is responsible for internet sharing is "NAT"
the same not available for esp32
however I found a repo about napt esp32 napt extender
but it seems that it requires Changing the default config files of esp idf plus I have no experience with the espressif IDF and trying the change the files is causing multiple errors
please let me know if you know how do we access the same in Arduino ide, I'll be grateful.

The ESP32 uses the WebServer.h instead of the ESP8266WiFi.h
see this example here that I found that works for both - so you see what you need to change:
#include <ESP8266WebServer.h> // <WebServer.h> for ESP32
#define PORT 80
const char* ssid = "Your SSID";
const char* pass = "Your Password";
ESP8266WebServer server(PORT); // WebServer server(PORT); for ESP32
 
void setup(){
  Serial.begin(115200); 
  Serial.print("Connecting to: ");
  Serial.println(ssid);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, pass);
   
  while(WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED){
    delay(500); 
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("WiFi connected");
  Serial.print("IP-Address of ESP8266 module: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
  
  server.begin();
}


thanks for the answer but did you even read the problem?
